# Vue.js set data in other component without event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently I'm using [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/). Behind the scenes it's using vue.js. I've made a custom vue component that need's to change data within another component.

That other component lives in the `node_modules` directory so I can't change the component code. The component is not using events so I can't change the data with that.

I was wondering is it possible to change data within another component without using events?

Comment: You've mentioned what the 3rd party component is **not** using but what **is** is using to get data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the code of the component where you want to set the data.
But if it has a ref you can do something like:

```
updateData: function() {
  this.$refs.xyComponent.clicked = true
}
```

Notice that the `$refs` are only populated after the render process.